# One single regular expression to match multiple alphanumeric words from 15 to 20 characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find all the words that have between 15 and 20 characters in a big string. And I want to avoid getting a long words with something else at the end (for ex `1234567890abcdef@asdf.com`). I don't want that to be a result, only words. Right now I'm spliting the string using white space as token and for each word I'm applying the following regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,20}$
```

Is there any chance to do both things using one regular expression?

I'm using C#.

Good examples to catch:

- `1234567890abcdeg`
- `qwertyuiopasdfgh`
- `1234567890abcdeg,` (catch it but remove ",")

Examples to avoid: `1234567890abcdeg@gmail.com`

Comment: What's your definition of "word"?

Comment: What programming language is this in?

Comment: Provide few more samples of matches and non-matches.

Comment: I added extra information.

Comment: Have you tried `\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,20}\b` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use start/end anchors (`^`/`$`), but word delimiters (`\b`):

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,20}(?=[\s,]|$)
```

I used `(?=[\s,]|$)` instead of the end delimiter to force a space character or a comma or the end of the string. Expand it as needed.
You may want to do likewise for the first `\b` if you need to, for instance: `(?<=\s|^)`.

Comment: @Francisco try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) before and after the alphanumerics:

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,20}\b
```

However, there's a small detail to take into account: uderscores ("`_`") are also considered a *word character*. The previous regex won't match the following text:

```
12345678901234567_
```

In order to avoid it, you can check if it's preceded and followed by either a `\b` or a "`_`", with [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

**Regex:**

```
(?<=\b|_)[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,20}(?=\b|_)
```